# Sort a multidimensional array descending by subarray count and preserve first level keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, preserve

I have an array such as:

```
$array = [
    'DEF' => [
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 1212, 'name' => 'Jane Doe', 'current' => 1],
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 3123121, 'name' => 'Door', 'current' => null],
    ],
    'ABC' => [
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 1234, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'current' => null],
    ],
    'WW' => [
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 1212, 'name' => 'Jane Doe', 'current' => 1],
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 3123121, 'name' => 'Door', 'current' => null],
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 64646, 'name' => 'Floor', 'current' => null],
    ]
];
```

And I want to sort this array by number ( count() ) of inner-array items descending (i.e. most items first), so I will have this array:

```
[
    'WW' => [
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 1212, 'name' => 'Jane Doe', 'current' => 1],
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 3123121, 'name' => 'Door', 'current' => null],
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 64646, 'name' => 'Floor', 'current' => null],
    ],
    'DEF' => [
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 1212, 'name' => 'Jane Doe', 'current' => 1],
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 3123121, 'name' => 'Door', 'current' => null],
    ],
    'ABC' => [
        ['type' => 1, 'id' => 1234, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'current' => null],
    ]
];
```

Can anyone suggest an efficient way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Why not `usort` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php ?

Comment: please use var_export for dumping arrays

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using [`uksort`](http://php.net/uksort):

```
uksort($array, function($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });
```

Using `array_multisort`:

```
array_multisort(array_map('count', $array), SORT_DESC, $array);
```

---

With PHP < 5.3:

```
function sort_cb($a, $b) {
    return count($b) - count($a);
}
uksort($array, 'sort_cb');
```

Comment: If you are using PHP < 5.3.0, you'll need to move that anonymous function out of there.

Comment: you should not use PHP < 5.3.0 ;)

Comment: The uksort() example didn't work as I lost my array keys ('ABC','DEF','WW') but the array_multisort() did work -- thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be [usort](http://de1.php.net/usort) instead of [uksort](http://de1.php.net/uksort)?

Comment: `uksort` sorts by Keys. Keys cannot be arrays and count does not count anything. `usort` compares values, which can be arrays.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (count($a) > count($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(
"AA" => array(
        array('type'=>'1', 'id'=>'2'),
        array('type'=>'2', 'id'=>'2')),
'BB' => array(
        array('type'=>'1', 'id'=>'2'),
        array('type'=>'2', 'id'=>'2'),
        array('type'=>'5', 'id'=>'2')),
'CC' => array(
        array('type'=>'1', 'id'=>'2'))
);  

usort($a, "cmp");

print_r($a);
?>
```

Comment: If you use PHP 7, you can now just do `count($a) <=> count($b)`; :)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tempArr = $sortedArr = array();
foreach ($myArr as $k => $v) $tempArr[$k] = count($v);
asort($tempArr);
foreach ($tempArr as $k => $v) $sortedArr = $myArr[$k];
```

Note that this will break if any of the array values are not themselves arrays, you may want to add an `is_array()` check somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

If you are only worried about sorting on size and not the actual quality, you can use the simplest approach to sort descending and preserve keys with `arsort()`.

[Array with fewer members is smaller, if key from operand 1 is not found in operand 2 then arrays are incomparable, otherwise - compare value by value (see following example)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#:%7E:text=Array%20with%20fewer%20members%20is%20smaller%2C%20if%20key%20from%20operand%201%20is%20not%20found%20in%20operand%202%20then%20arrays%20are%20incomparable%2C%20otherwise%20%2D%20compare%20value%20by%20value%20(see%20following%20example))

In the event that you have multiple rows with the same size, then they will be further sorted descending based on their actual data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ErXp9))

```
arsort($array);
var_export($array);
```