# sort an array on maximum occurrences

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm new to php and I feel that this language has some really good set of sorting functions for arrays

I have an input array below containing the books ,  readers and price

```
$input[]=array("Harrypotter","John",50);
$input[]=array("Twilight","John",60);
$input[]=array("Harrypotter","Jack",80);
$input[]=array("Gonegirl","marion",90);
$input[]=array("Gonegirl","test",90);
$input[]=array("Gonegirl","John",90);
$input[]=array("Gonegirl","eliza",90);
```

I want to sort the array on first field in such a way that the book which repeats more number of times should come first , the expected O/p is something like this

```
$input[]=array("Gonegirl","marion",90);
$input[]=array("Gonegirl","test",90);
$input[]=array("Gonegirl","John",90);
$input[]=array("Gonegirl","eliza",90);
$input[]=array("Harrypotter","Jack",80);
$input[]=array("Harrypotter","John",50);
$input[]=array("Twilight","John",60);
```

I'm able to copy the first field in separate array and get the occurrence by using **array_count_values** and i'm able to get the expected output through **array_multi_sort** but it sorts only by alphabetical order of the first field .

Any efficient way of arriving at the solution would be helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first have to establish a count of how often each value occurs, then you can write a comparison function that sorts by those values:

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_map('current', $input));
usort($input, function (array $a, array $b) use ($counts) {
    return $counts[$b[0]] - $counts[$a[0]];
});
```

Comment: works like a charm tested for different inputs ,but it sorts in the ascending order . What does the call back function do ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476. Just reverse the `$a` and `$b` parameters if you want it the other way around.

Comment: @SanthoshPai You wanted to sort it that it ends with 80, 50, 60 and his answer ends with: 50, 80, 60?

Comment: Hello @Rizier123 , i actually wanted only for maximum occurences of first field .

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $input = array();

    $input[]=array("Harrypotter","John",50);
    $input[]=array("Twilight","John",60);
    $input[]=array("Harrypotter","Jack",80);
    $input[]=array("Gonegirl","marion",90);
    $input[]=array("Gonegirl","test",90);
    $input[]=array("Gonegirl","John",90);
    $input[]=array("Gonegirl","eliza",90);

    function cmp($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
    }

    usort($input, "cmp");

    print_r($input);

?>
```

Comment: Why do you compare prices instead of names?

Comment: @u_mulder Because he wants to order the array by the prices

Comment: no it should be on the maximum occurences of first field ie the book name

Comment: `I want to sort the array on first field`

Comment: Replace `return strcmp($b[2], $a[2]);` with `return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);` and done

Answer (score 0):

```
array_multisort(array_map('count', $input), SORT_DESC, $input);
```

PS: From [PHP Sort a multidimensional array by number of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433569/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-number-of-items)

**Update**:

```
array_multisort(array_map(function ($fld) {return $fld[0];}, $input), SORT_ASC, $input);
```

Comment: no it still sorts in alphabetical order ,need on maximum number of occurences of first field