# Unable to Sort multi dimentional array by items inside

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array by number ( count() ) of inner-array items descending (i.e. most items first)

This is my array,

```
Array
(
    [Itm01] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 7908
                    [col2] => 7181
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17024
                    [col1] => 1039
                    [col2] => 7181
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [col1] => 1039
                    [col2] => 7181
                )

        )

    [Itm02] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 260
                    [col1] => 1039
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 9149
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 0
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 7333
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 9049
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 7333
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 9049
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 8217
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 7516
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 82
                    [col1] => 1039
                    [col2] => 8964
                )

        )

    [Itm03] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 7908
                    [col2] => 7276
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [col1] => 9049
                    [col2] => 7276
                )

        )

    [Itm04] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 82
                    [col1] => 8217
                    [col2] => 8217
                )

        )

)
```

But I want item with index 'Itm02' as the first since it has more items. To be honest I want the same thing as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433569/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-number-of-items). But when I did this,

```
$warehouses = uksort($warehouses, function($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });
```

But it returns an empty array. It would be great if someone can help.

Comment: Uksort sorts array in place, does not return it. After `uksort($warehouses,..` the array is already sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`uksort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) returns a boolean.

Try the following:

```
uksort($warehouses, function($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });

print_r($warehouses);
```

Answer (score 1):

> [**array_multisort()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) : Sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays

```
array_multisort(array_map('count', $a), SORT_DESC, $a);
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/EATkk

Comment: Think this also returns boolean bt thanks a lot bro